# Django - Found another file with the destination path django - during deploying app

Tags: python, django

trying to deploy my app to uwsgi server

my settings file:

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/root/djangoApp/staticRoot/"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/home/root/djangoApp/static/',
]
```

and url file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #urls
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and if I try to execute the command:

> python manage.py collectstatic

Then some files are okay ( admin files ), but I see an error next to files from static folder. The error is like:

> Found another file with the destination path 'js/bootstrap.min.js'. It
>   will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If
>   this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique
>   path.

and have no idea what can I do to solve it.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is there bootstrap.min.js at multiple location try doing a find ?

Comment: No ,bootstrap is only inside static folder ( and staticRoot after run command )

Answer (score 1):

The two paths you have in STATICFILES_DIRS are the same. So Django copies the files from one of them, then goes on to the second and tries to copy them again, only to see the files already exist.

Remove one of those entries, preferably the second.

Comment: Wow, that works! thank you so much. But even thoughI can execute the collectstatic command, my browser still doesn't see the static files

Comment: The requested URL /static/js/scripts.js was not found on this server.

Comment: do you now why ?

Comment: What have you set up to serve those files in production?

Comment: I have only changed the urls and settings files ( static ) - I pasted everything in main post in this topic

Comment: You need to configure your webserver (presumably nginx) to serve the files in the static folder.

Answer (score 0):

do you have more than one application?
If so, you should put any file on a subdirectory with a unique name (like the app name for example).
collectstatic collects files from all the /static/ subdirectories, and if there is a duplication, it throw this error.

Comment: I don't get it. sorry ( I am beginner :-) ). I have some js/img/css files in my static folder. Could you write me step by step what should I do to deploy my app ?